# ASP.net mvc ActionResult parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        _userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
    else
    {
        var user = UserService.GetUserByUserName(username);

        if (user != null)
        {
            _userId = user.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Routines");
        }
    }

    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetUserHomeData()
{
    return Json(CreateHomeViewModel(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetUserStatisticsOverview()
{
    return Json(CreateUserStatisticsOverviewViewModel(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I have problem with parameter username of ActionResult Index. I've monitored username variable and if I type url like this: www.test.com/profile/someUserName

Variable username is assigned these values:

  1. someUserName

  2. GetUserHomeData

  3. GetUserStatisticsOverview

I call these Get methods from my javaScript file, why is this happening and how can I prevent this, i.e. catch only "someUsername"

Here is my route config:

```
routes.MapRoute("Profile", "profile/{userName}",
                    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

Here is how I access Get methods (I'm using Angular's $http)

```
getResult: function() {

    var input = $http.get("/Profile/GetUserHomeData");

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    deferred.resolve(input);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: What is your route-Table looking like?

Comment: @Grumbler85 I've edited post and added code for routes

Comment: And how do you access the GetUserHomeData for example?

Comment: Please, specify the tested urls, and the resulting parameter, and controller action invoked.

Comment: @Grumbler85 I've edited post again and added that piece of code

Comment: @JotaBe well for url www.test.com/profile/bla Action which was invoked was only Index and username was assigned firstly bla, then GetUserHomeData, and at last GetUserStatisticsOverview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are probably calling something like: `@Url.Action("GetUserHomeData", "Profile")` inside your JS, but this will be catched by the first route and the action there is `Index` and nothing else.
You can eliminate the problem by just removing the route

```
routes.MapRoute("Profile", "profile/{userName}",
                new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

alternatively you can rewrite the rule (that it does not match the controller-name):

```
routes.MapRoute("ProfileShortRoute", "p/{userName}",
                new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

This will lead to Urls like this: `http://domain/Profile/?userName=someUser` or `http://domain/p/someUser`

Comment: Is there any other way around this ?

Comment: You can rewrite the route to not match the controller name