# Next / Previous Week Functions in ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

So I've created a function that navigates through every week and displays the timereports data in database, the problem is that it can only navigate once and not further, I need some help.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ReportSystem.ViewModel
{
    public static class WeekConverter
    {
        public static DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(int year, int weekOfYear)
        {
            var jan1 = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            var daysOffset = DayOfWeek.Thursday - jan1.DayOfWeek;
            var firstThursday = jan1.AddDays(daysOffset);
            var cal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
            var firstWeek = cal.GetWeekOfYear(firstThursday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
            var weekNum = weekOfYear;

            if (firstWeek <= 1)
            {
                weekNum -= 1;
            }

            var result = firstThursday.AddDays(weekNum * 7);

            return result.AddDays(-3);
        }

        public static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
        {
            var day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);

            if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
            {
                time = time.AddDays(3);
            }

            return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
        } 
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ReportSystem.Models.TimeReports>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Week: @((DateTime)ViewBag.Date)</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "TimeReports") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Day Off", "Index", "Other")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Consultants.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalHours)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TimeType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OnSite)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Consultants.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalHours)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OnSite)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Previous Week", "PreviousWeek", "TimeReports") |
    @Html.ActionLink("Next Week", "NextWeek", "TimeReports")
</p>
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ReportSystem.Models;
using ReportSystem.ViewModel;

namespace ReportSystem.Controllers
{
    public class TimeReportsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ReportsDatabaseEntities _db = new ReportsDatabaseEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var weekNr = WeekConverter.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now);
            var startTime = WeekConverter.FirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Year, weekNr);
            var endTime = startTime.AddDays(6).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
            var consultantId = (int)Session["Id"];

            var timeReports = _db.TimeReports.Where(s => s.Date >= startTime && s.Date <= endTime)
                .Where(s => s.ConsultantID == consultantId).ToList();

            ViewBag.Date = startTime;

            return View(timeReports);
        }

        public ActionResult PreviousWeek()
        {
            var weekNr = WeekConverter.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now); //The value keeps staying at same week...
            var startTime = WeekConverter.FirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Year, weekNr);
            startTime = startTime.AddDays(-7);
            var endTime = startTime.AddDays(6).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
            var consultantId = (int)Session["Id"];

            var timeReports = _db.TimeReports.Where(s => s.Date >= startTime && s.Date <= endTime)
                .Where(s => s.ConsultantID == consultantId).ToList();

            ViewBag.Date = startTime;

            return View("Index", timeReports);
        }

        public ActionResult NextWeek()
        {
            var weekNr = WeekConverter.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now);//The value keeps staying at same week...
            var startTime = WeekConverter.FirstDateOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Year, weekNr);
            startTime = startTime.AddDays(7);
            var endTime = startTime.AddDays(6).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
            var consultantId = (int)Session["Id"];

            var timeReports = _db.TimeReports.Where(s => s.Date >= startTime && s.Date <= endTime)
                .Where(s => s.ConsultantID == consultantId).ToList();

            ViewBag.Date = startTime;

            return View("Index", timeReports);
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have already asked this a few hours earlier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141348/previous-next-week-functions-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework). Please delete one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

this ActionResult "NextWeek()" need started week parameter or else a week as the same all the time (DateTime.Now)

create map routes with parameter i'm not shure but look this to build map root

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "TimeReports", 
    action = "PreviousWeek", 
    WeekStart = UrlParameter.Optional})
```

look this for help to build map routes [ASP.net mvc ActionResult parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025324/asp-net-mvc-actionresult-parameter)

Comment: How is the parameter supposed to look?

Comment: in view something like this `@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week", "PreviousWeek", "TimeReports", new { WeekStart =@ViewBag.PreviousDate });` and in the model  `ActionResult PreviousWeek( DateTime WeekStart  )`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the initial view renders a collection of time reports for the current week, and you want links to redirect to a view that renders a collection of reports for the next/previous weeks, then you need one method that has a parameter identifying the week. Dealing with a `DateTime` property can be problematic, so for this example I'll use an `int` identifying the week relative to the current week

```
public ActionResult Index(int ID = 0)
{
  DateTime firstOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(ID * 7).FirstOfWeek() // see notes below
  DateTime lastofWeek = firstOfWeek.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);
  var consultantId = (int)Session["Id"];
  var timeReports = _db.TimeReports.Where(s => s.Date >= firstOfWeek && s.Date <= lastofWeek).Where(s => s.ConsultantID == consultantId); // don't need .ToList()
  ViewBag.PreviousWeek = ID - 1; // better to use a view model rather than ViewBag
  ViewBag.NextWeek = ID + 1; 
  return View("Index", timeReports);
}
```

Then in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<ReportSystem.Models.TimeReports>
<table>
  ....
</table>
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week", "Index", "TimeReports", new { ID = ViewBag.PreviousWeek })
// Assume you don't want to navigate to a future week
@if (ViewBag.NextWeek < 0)
{
  @Html.ActionLink("Next Week", "Index", "TimeReports" new { ID = ViewBag.NextWeek })
}
```

I cant understand what that code in your `WeekConverter` class is supposed to be doing. If you want to get the first day of the week then create an simple extension method

```
// Extension method to return the first  day of the week (Sunday).
public static DateTime FirstOfWeek(this DateTime date)
{
  return date.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday - date.DayOfWeek);
}
// Extension method to return the first working day of the week (Monday).
public static DateTime FirstOfWorkingWeek(this DateTime date)
{
  return date.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - date.DayOfWeek);
}
```